# Compiler Errors in a for statement?

Tags: java, for-loop, compiler-errors

I'm just trying to write a simple code that produces 5 smiley faces on the same line.
Ex output= :) :) :) :) :)

And I don't understand why this code won't compile.

```
public class SmileGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {
            System.out.print(":) ");
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I get are:

```
SmileGenerator.java:9: error: ';' expected  
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {  
                      ^  
SmileGenerator.java:9: error: illegal start of type  
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {  
                       ^  
SmileGenerator.java:9: error: illegal start of expression  
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {  
                        ^  
SmileGenerator.java:9: error: ';' expected  
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {  
                         ^  
SmileGenerator.java:9: error: illegal start of expression  
        for (int i=0,i<6,i++) {


                        ^
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax. The expressions within `for (...)` are separated by semi-colons (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)). Change your commas to semi-colons, thus:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

... and this will fix your compiler warnings. If you look closely at the first compiler error message, you'll see `';' expected` and a rough indication of where. This will help you diagnose such issues in the future.

Once your code compiles, the next step is to fix your bug. If you want 5 smiley faces, use:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the java for loop, the separator is ";" character, not ","